# Microsoft Visual Studios 2010 - creating a new project in regular C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm relatively new to VS (only used it once before for a simple project) and all I want to do is create a new C file for my project. When I go to add file to the project I created, the only available language option I'm remotely familiar with is C++. I chose that and tried saving the file as a regular C file, which VS let me do, but it saved it as a separate file outside of my project. Is there a way I can add this C file to my project? I've tried playing around with some of the options and I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: I've always found the easiest way to do this is just to add a .cpp file and then rename it to be .c.  There may be a better way to do this; this has always just been easy enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **Solution Explorer**, Click on the **Source Files** folder. Press `Shift + Alt + A` to add an existing item to the sources folder. Then just choose your `.c` file.

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Source Files folder from Solution Explorer -> Add -> Existing Item ... and choose your file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of VS handy at the moment and cannot check, but I believe it should be possible to create a new .c source file.  What you can do for sure is to create your .c file outside of VS and then drag it into the solution explorer.  Always works.